# databinding with parameters to oracle via sql

Tags: c#, asp.net, parameters, sqldatasource, linked-server

We have a linked server set up in SQL Server to an oracle server.

I need to populate a gridview with some data. But I find that when I use a parameter with the datasource the query is very slow. However if I hard code the value in place of a parameter the query is much quicker.

The parameter is set from a textbox control with auto-postback.

I've coded it like so...

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsRepairs" runat="server" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT REPAIR_NO + '-' + LINE_NO AS SELECT_OPTION, CUSTOMER_NO, DATE_ADDED, YOUR_REFERENCE, PART_NO, DESCRIPTION, SERIAL_NO, REPAIR_STATUS 
                             FROM TEST..INFOVIEW.CRO_LINES 
                            WHERE CUSTOMER_NO = @CUSTOMER_NO;" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>">
                <SelectParameters>
                    <asp:ControlParameter Name="CUSTOMER_NO" ControlID="txtAccountNo" PropertyName="Text" DbType="String" Direction="Input" />
                </SelectParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I believe the extra time is due to datatype conversions, but I want to know how this could be sped up. It's not acceptable to us to wait 15+ seconds for the page to load with data when using the parameter method.

I only seem to have the option for `DBType="String"`, but the field type on the source table in oracle is a `varchar(20)`.

Is there any way that I can improve this? I have no control over the way the datasources are set up. I have to work with a linked server through SQL Server, and apart from this, it's been more than acceptable at returning data in good time.

Please let me know if I need to give more information!